# Google Armor - Rate limit based on the Url or Path

Tags: rate-limiting

Is there a way to identify clients for rate limit based on the Url or Path of the requests? The parameter --enforce-on-key of the rule accepts HTTP-HEADERS, but not sure how to identify the path or the uri.

Thank you